# Multi-site clear cache

Tags: multi-sites

We want to clear the multiple sites cache from one site, currently we have multi-site configuration. Is there any module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily [configure drush aliases](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php) for this.

Having properly configured drush brings so many benefits, especially if you work with multiple environnements for your sites.

As an example, say you have aliases defined for example.com as follows:,

@example.local, @example.staging, @example.prod

See a status of all 3 sites:

```
drush @example st
```

Clear the cache on local env:

```
drush @example.local cc all
```

Dump production database and load it into local:

```
drush @example.prod sqldump | drush @example.dev sqlc
```

Anyways, you get the idea. Packing your drush.rc file with your project in git (shove it in /sites/all/drush/drushrc.php ) will allow anyone working on those projects to have those aliases fully defined on every code checkout.
Happy codings, cheers!

- Lots of examples on drush aliases via google, here is a pretty well written one: https://www.monarchdigital.com/blog/2012-10-10/drush-aliases